# How Can I Rotate a Bone by More Than 360 Degrees?

Tags: rigging, bones, transforms

I have downloaded a model from Sketchfab. It's a space ship.
This ship was not rigged, so I've tried to rig it myself. But I have a problem: I would like to rotate the rotors of the aircraft. So I tried to rotate the bone that I attached to the rotor, but I found out that when I try to rotate the bone it rotates only by 360°.

Can somebody tell me how I can rotate my rotor by any amount?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Markus von Broady says, "It's impossible to go outside of 360 degrees range in quaternion".

So open the <kbd>N</kbd> panel, choose *Euler* instead of *Quaternion* and enter the value you want on the rotation axis you want.

Comment: Thank you very much. when I have change it to ZXY Euler it works fine

Comment: It's impossible to go outside of 360 degrees range in quaternions: *"[...]rotation angles differing precisely by the natural period will be encoded into identical quaternions and recovered angles will be limited to { 0 , 2 π } (in radians)"*  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation

Comment: ok thanks for the precision, I'm going to edit my answer